# How to put customized value when records not fetched in CASE WHEN using SQL ORACLE?

Tags: sql, oracle, case

Suppose I have two tables as Table1 & Table2 and the data are as below:
Table1

```
Id
__
id1
id2
id3
id4
id5
```

Table2

```
Id  rank
--  ---
Id1 1
Id2 2
```

Now, I want to make a orcale SQL query which returns as below:

```
Id  rank
--  ---
Id1 1
Id2 2
Id3 0
Id4 0
Id5 0
```

I have made following SQL but it does not return desired result.

```
SELECT TAB1.ID,(SELECT CASE
    WHEN TAB2.RANK IS NULL THEN TAB2.RANK
    ELSE 0
    END FROM TABLE2 TAB2 WHERE  TAB2.ID=TAB1.ID) as RANK FROM TABLE1 TAB1;
```

It returns as below:

```
Id  rank
--  ---
Id1 1
Id2 2
Id3 null
Id4 null
Id5 null
```

Comment: I think you meant `when tab2.rank is not null`?

Answer (score 2):

Should be a simple left join:

```
SELECT tab1.id, coalesce(tab2.rank,0) as rank
FROM tab1
LEFT JOIN tab2 ON tab1.id = tab2.id
```

Answer (score 1):

use left join and `coalesce()`.
 coalesce() returns 1st non null value, so when id will not match it will return 0

```
 select t1.id,coalesce(t2.rank,0)
 from table1 t1
 left join table2 t2
 on t1.id=t2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

use coalesce() function

```
SELECT TAB1.ID,coalesce((SELECT CASE
    WHEN TAB2.RANK IS NULL THEN TAB2.RANK
    ELSE 0
    END FROM TABLE2 TAB2 WHERE  TAB2.ID=TAB1.ID),0) as RANK FROM TABLE1 TAB1;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using `coalesce()` and `left join`?

```
select t1.id, coalesce(t2.rank, 0) as rank
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id = t2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct, and if the `id` column is unique, it's definitely the way I'd do it.

However, to explain how to do what you want using a scalar subquery, you need to do the scalar subquery first and then work out what to do with the results, so it would look something like:

```
select id,
       case when rank is null then 0 else rank end rank1,
       coalesce (rank, 0) rank2,
       nvl (rank, 0) rank3
from   (select tab1.id,
               (select tab2.rank from table2 tab2 where tab2.id = tab1.id) rank
        from   table1 tab1);
```

N.B. I've given you 3 ways of producing the rank you're after:

- `CASE` - this is okay to use, but a bit wordy.
- `COALESCE` - returns the first non-null value in the list of parameters provided
- `NVL` - it's ok to use this in this situation, since the second value is a constant. However, `NVL` always evaluates both parameters, regardless of whether it needs to or not. If the second parameter is a function, it will get run every single time, even if the first parameter is not null. Both `CASE` and `COALESCE` will perform logic short-circuiting, meaning they will stop at the first condition that evaluates to true.

In general, my preferred option is to use `COALESCE`.

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
select a.id,case when b.rank is not null then
b.rank else 0 end
from 
table1 a,table2 b where
a.id=b.id;
```